# React-native App Crashing in Release mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My app is crashing in release mode but working fine in debug mode. This problem is caused due to `Platform` check.

Actually the app is working fine without that `Platform` check code.

These are `Keyboard` events on which I am performing animation.

```
_keyboardDidShow = e => {
  keyboardHeight = e.endCoordinates.height,
  height = Platform.OS == "ios" ? keyboardHeight : 0
Animated.timing(this.state.bottomPadding, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 150
}).start();
Animated.timing(this.state.keyboardHeight, {
  toValue: height,
  duration: 150,
}).start();
this.setState({ isFocused: true });
}

_keyboardDidHide = () => {
this.setState({ isFocused: false });
Animated.timing(this.state.bottomPadding, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 150
}).start();
Animated.timing(this.state.keyboardHeight, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 0
}).start();
}
```

This is part of code which I am animating.

```
customFocusNavigator = () => {
return (
  <Animated.View
    style={[styles.FocusNavigator,{ bottom: this.state.keyboardHeight }]}
  >
    <View style={styles.FocusNavigatorDirectionBox}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.state.index > 0
            ? this["customtext" + (this.state.index - 1)].changeFocus()
            : this["customtext0"].changeFocus();
        }}
        style={[
          styles.bottomSubView,
          { borderRightColor: constant.COLOR.WHITE, borderRightWidth: 1 }
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.FocusNavigatorText}>Previous</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.state.index < 4
            ? this["customtext" + (this.state.index + 1)].changeFocus()
            : this["customtext0"].changeFocus();
        }}
        style={styles.bottomSubView}
      >
        <Text style={styles.FocusNavigatorText}>Next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}
    >
      <Text style={[styles.FocusNavigatorText, { fontWeight: "bold" }]}>
        Done
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Animated.View>
  );
 };
```

Rest is state

```
 keyboardHeight: new Animated.Value(0),
```

If I am giving hardcoded value suppose 300 in place of height in `KeyboardDidShow` the app is not crashing but after adding `Platform` check the start crashing in release mode. I want platform specific height so `Platform` check is needed.

Comment: Do you have error logs? if yes, share them on your question

Comment: Sorry, I don't have error log of release mode.

Comment: @TanvirSingh then you need to obtain those. That's the first step to solving your problem. You can generate a release build (for Android you can follow https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) which you then can install using `adb`. When you've done than, start `adb logcat` in a terminal/command prompt window and see what error is thrown when your app crashes.

Comment: I think error in this line "keyboardHeight = e.endCoordinates.height," . Remove "," or add ";" instead of  "," .

Comment: @VishalJadav No it is not working even though

Comment: [Info] 01-15 19:16:51.647 11147 11189 E ReactNativeJS: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

Comment: Error in logcat.

Comment: Hey, Use crash analytics offered by firebase and report the bug here. Or use non-stock android devices, any crash will result in "Report a bug" page by the OS.

Comment: From your comment, it look like e.endCoordinates may be undefined. Can you try this:

if (e.endCoordinates) {
   keyboardHeight = e.endCoordinates.height
} else {
   keyboardHeight = // some random height
}

Comment: tried but it didn't work.

Comment: thank you, adb logcat saved my life, i found a fatal error with it